# Equivalence Relation, Is [15]r = [-13]r

Tags: equivalence-relations

For the equivalence relation on the integers given by $(x, y) ∈ R$ if and only if $7$ divides $x - y$, $7 | (x - y)$. Is $[15]_R = [-13]_R$? Is $[15]_R = [13]_R$ (the $R$'s would be subscripts denoting they are elements of $R$). I'm not sure where to start here, are these asking about symmetry?

Comment: This may need some clarification.  In your first question, are you asking if 15 is equivalent to -13 in the sense defined earlier?  But then, don't you just have to check whether or not 7 divides 15 - (-13) ?

Comment: Yes it would be in the sense defined earlier, but I guess that's what I'm unsure of if that's what it's asking with that notation

Comment: Well, if it helps at all:  it's not a standard notation.  At least, I've never seen it before.  For a general equivalence relation people just write "x ~ y" or, if you want to emphasize the particular equivalence, maybe "x  $\sim_R$ y.  In your specific case, by the way, there is a standard notation:  $x \equiv y $ mod (7)  or simply x = y mod (7).

Comment: Sorry the notation was just updated, not sure if that helps but I haven't seen it expressed that way before either which is why I ask.

Comment: In any case:  I am pretty sure they are just asking you to decide whether or not 15 is equivalent to -13 via the equivalence relation R.

Comment: Agreed, so would it then be asking if 7 divides 15 - (-13) and 15 - 13 or would it be asking if x mod 7 = 7 mod 7? Sorry for my ignorance on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25944/discussion-between-nati0n-and-lulu).

Comment: ok, but only for a short time (nearly bed time in my world).

Answer (score 1):

An element $x$ is in the equivalence class ${[y]}_R$ if it satisfies the equivalence relation. 
$$\begin{align}x\in {[y]}_R \;& \iff\; xRy \\ & \iff\; 7\mid (y-x)\end{align}$$

Now two equivalence classes will be the same if they contain the same elements.   This means that: $${[x]}_R={[y]}_R \;\iff\; xRy$$

So we have $\;{[15]}_R={[{-}13]}_R\;$ iff $\;7\mid({-}13-15)$, and that $\;{[15]}_R={[{+}13]}_R \;$ iff $\;7\mid(13-15)$

Which is true or false?

---

The truth statement, $\,m\mid n\,$, means $m$ divides $n$ with no remainder.  That is, there is some integer $k$ such that $\,km = n\,$ .